# External Error Process responce (second post)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm facing a problem with my code below where the lblMessage is updated based on the input to a field. The purpose of the code is then to show either a validation error, a success message (the MessageICCID) or a process error message.

In the update below, once the status has been set to P, then another process will change this to S. When set to S, sometimes the below code not catch the Status S? and it's keep loading until timeout, i do appreciate if we can update the lblmessage when status set to S? I need to detect this and show on lblMessage once status set to S?

How can I best allow for errors arising in the update process or the external process?

Here is what I have tried so far:

SQL Select Statement as below:

1- (GetDataByNumber)

```
SELECT FirstName, ICCID, Message, MessageICCID, SecondName, Status, StatusICCID, id, number, submitICCID, userid FROM ChangesimLive WHERE (number = @number)
```

2- (UpdateICCIDByNumber)

```
UPDATE       ChangesimLive  SET ICCID = @ICCID, StatusICCID = @StatusICCID,userid=@userid WHERE (number = @number)
```

''

```
 protected void btnActivate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Text = "";
    if (txtICCID.Text.Length != 19)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Incorrect ICCID. Enter 19 Digit ICCID";
        SetFocus(txtICCID);

        return;
    }
    DataTable dt = ch.GetDataByNumber(txtNumber.Text);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        ch.UpdateICCIDByNumber(txtICCID.Text, "P", Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"].ToString()), txtNumber.Text);
        while (true)
        {
            dt = ch.GetDataByNumber(txtNumber.Text);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                if (dt.Rows[0]["StatusICCID"].ToString() == "S")
                {


                    lblMessage.Text = dt.Rows[0]["MessageICCID"].ToString();
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What errors are you talking about in your question? You mean sql errors for the update query? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a condition for the while loop to break:

```
while (true)
{
    dt = ch.GetDataByNumber(txtNumber.Text);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[0]["StatusICCID"].ToString() == "S")
        {
            lblMessage.Text = dt.Rows[0]["MessageICCID"].ToString();
            break;
        } else { break; } // break if the wrong row?
    }
    else { break; } // break when there are no rows.
}
```

Comment: I've provided a possible answer; "any help please" doesn't really explain why this solution doesn't work. Please provide more details as to why this solution doesn't work.

Comment: First thank you for your help sire, second, This still not update the lblMessage when the status set to S? So now:sometimes works and lblMessage updated AND sometimes not? so now any help please? Thank you

Comment: @ Metro Smurf, Any help please? i want the LblMessage to return always the message when status Set to S...

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can provide. Maybe set the `lblMessage.Text` to some value in both of the break conditions and you can see where the while loop is failing?